# query using column from junction table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `Node` entity with a many to many relationship with itself through `Edge`

```
var Node = db.define('nodes', {
    'name': sequelize.STRING
});

var Edge = db.define('edges', {
    'weight': sequelize.STRING
});

Node.hasMany(Node, { as: 'parents', foreignKey: 'parent_id', through: Edge});
Node.hasMany(Node, { as: 'children', foreignKey: 'child_id', through: Edge});
```

I want to get a nodes children which are created after a specific time using a query like the following

```
node.getChildren({ 
    include: [Edge],
    where: ['createdAt > ?', 1413000965754] 
}).complete(function(err, children){
    // ...
});
```

but I cant get it to work.